# Highchart with float data type and with max value on Y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to to plot high chart with float data type on Y-axis but with sql server's max float limit. I am not able to plot the chart using maximum float value.

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/e3ary1fj/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function(){
                    return this.value.toExponential(3).replace('e-','E-0');
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [1e-8,0.355e-8]
        }]

    });
});
```

Please manipulate data like following in above mentioned link:

```
series: [{
data: [1e-8,1.79E+308]
}]
```

When float has big exponential value like sql server's maximum value then I am not able to plot the highchart. Please try following to reproduce this issue:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function(){
                        return this.value.toExponential(3).replace('e-','E-0');
                    }
                }
            },
    
            series: [{
                data: [1e-8,1.79E+308]
            }]
    
        });
    });
```

Thanks,
Dhirendra

Comment: Hi @Dhirendra Medsing, Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve?